# Is it still possible to download Census 2000 data at the level of the Metropolitan Statistical Area?

Tags: usa, data.gov, us-census

If you go to the web page for the 2000 Census:

https://www.census.gov/main/www/cen2000.html

they don't list MSA's anywhere. If you click on "FactFinder", it just links to the Factfinder for the 2010 Census. The Demographic Profiles are just either for the whole country or at the state level, not the MSA level. Is it still possible to get these data?

The raw data

http://www2.census.gov/census_2000/datasets/Summary_File_1/

are just as the state level too. Is there a way to get 2000 data through the FactFinder? Is there a tutorial on the Factfinder? It seems so hard to use!

Comment: if you're willing to work with the microdata, [the pums files have msas](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/united%20states%20decennial%20census%20public%20use%20microdata%20sample%20%28pums%29).

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Thanks. That website mentions the annual ACS data. Is that available for MSA's? Are those the 1-year estimates that I see in the factfinder?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen or not, but I highly recommend [IPUMS](https://usa.ipums.org/usa/).  As Anthony mentions, I think inevitably someone might ask of your data, "MSA is nice, but could we get more detail?..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the geographic categorization is different for MSA between 2000 and 2010. If you use [this link](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/DEC/00_SF1/H001/0100000US.38000.003), and select "BACK TO ADVANCED SEARCH", it will bring you back to the search bar with the geographic level I specified. Since this level only seems to apply to 2000, you'll be getting table listings for the 2000 Census.

In the future, if you open the Topics tab --> expand the Year drop-down list, select 2000 and then go into the geography tab, it will only list available geography levels in 2000, and MSA appears on the list.

[image: How to Select Surveys for 2000]

Comment: I guess I don't see how you got the factfinder to only show data for a certain year. Maybe it's super obvious and I'm just missing it, but I don't see that option.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, bulk summary file data for MSAs and other geographies which are not by definition contained by state boundaries is in http://www2.census.gov/census_2000/datasets/Summary_File_1/0Final_National/  but you're probably better off using FactFinder, as advised, or IPUMS if you want someone else to deal with the fact that the boundaries of MSAs have changed since 2000.

Here's [a Census Bureau page about historical delineations of MSAs](https://www.census.gov/population/metro/data/pastmetro.html).